# Populated DataGridView is showing 0 cells for GetCellCount

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a populated DataGridView from an OdbcAdapter that is showing items. However, I'm having trouble with `GetCellDisplayRectangle(column, row, overflowFlag)` because, according to `GetCellCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Visible)` there are no cells on the DataGridView.

Does anybody know what is causing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: post you comment as an answer, it makes a good resource for other users in the future.

Comment: @DavidHall I shall. I have a limit of not answering my own questions until 8 hours after I ask them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was happening in a handler of a class inheriting from `DataGridView`. The problem was in the handler `GetCellDisplayRectangle()` and the other related function were being called by implicitely referencing `this`.